# How make allure with okhttp

Tags: java, okhttp, allure

I'm trying to create allure reports on API tests.The difficulty is that I work with the OKHTTP3 library.

I wrote the code as recommended and when running the tests, allure-reports is filled with data. The difficulty is that the data is in HTML format and not in XML, and as a result, when you run allureServe, the report is empty.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new AllureOkHttp3())
                .build();
```

The client is used in every request in every test.

Comment: Have you added `allure serve` and `allure generate` properties?

Comment: I'm not sure. How exactly and where should they be added?

Comment: Sorry, they are commands and not properties, check this out: [`allure serve`](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_report_generation) & [`allure generate`](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_allurecodeception)

Comment: It seems like it is, in any case, in gradle I have a method for both report and serve

Comment: Seems to be something complex,  please [give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question